# JQuery autosuggest not working after searched once

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a search textbox where a user starts typing in, This fires some javascript which runs a method to call a stored procedure to find the suggested text for the user to click. This works fine on page load. When the user selects an item from the suggested text and hits 'Search' the gridview below has been filtered accordingly. However, when the user goes back to the search textbox to search for something else - the auto-suggest is no longer working. Can't seem to figure out why? It only works again when I refresh the whole page, therefore losing my filtered gridview.

.JS file:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    SearchColumn();


    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById('searching').click(); return false;
        }
    }


});

function SearchColumn() {
    $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Exception.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                data: "{'ColumnName':'" + document.getElementById('exampleFormControlSelect1').value + "', 'SearchValue':'" + document.getElementById('SearchInput').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        response(data.d);
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {

                alert(result);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
}
```

ASPX:

```
  <asp:updatepanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> 
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
     <div class="form-group">

         <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Select column to search on: </label>
    <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Select Column" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="IRN" Value="IRN"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Application Number" Value="ApplicationNumber"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Measure Code" Value="MEASURECODE"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Instructor" Value="Instructor"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Overdue" Value="Overdue"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Exception" Value="ExceptionDesc"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox id="SearchInput" runat="server" class="form-control autosuggest" placeholder="Search" type="text"> </asp:TextBox>
     <div class="input-group-append" runat="server">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="searching" onserverclick="Search_Click" runat="server" type="button">Search</button>
    </div>
        </div>
 </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:updatepanel>
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string ColumnName, string SearchValue)
{

    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].test", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subteamno", SubTeam);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column", ColumnName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", SearchValue);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        result.Add(dr[ColumnName].ToString());
    }

    result = result.Distinct().ToList();
    return result;




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an UpdatePanel, on postback you have to re-initialize the javascript objects. The UpdatePanel is giving some function to do that on client side, and your code will be as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    SearchColumn();
    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById('searching').click(); return false;
        }
    }
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
    //prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);     
});

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
   // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init the Autocomplete
   SearchColumn();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your  will get recreated when the user clicks your button and does a postback. 
Jquery provides the 'live()' method that watches the dom for changes and reattaches events if needed :

http://api.jquery.com/live/ - "Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."

So changing your code to :

```
function SearchColumn() {

   $(".autosuggest").live('load',function(){
       $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Exception.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                data: "{'ColumnName':'" + document.getElementById('exampleFormControlSelect1').value + "', 'SearchValue':'" + document.getElementById('SearchInput').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        response(data.d);
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {

                alert(result);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
}


});
```

Should probably fix it, But it'd be better to kick it off after the postback, as live() isn't very performant ...